# Jenkins unable to invoke SENCHA CMD

Tags: java, extjs, ant, jenkins

I'm trying to configure Sencha CMD in Jenkins. I have added the classpath of Sencha in bash_profile.

If I try to invoke Sencha CMD on console, it works without any issues, but if I try invoke Sencha CMD through Jenkins I'm observing this error

```
Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sencha": error=2, No such file or directory 
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041) 
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617) 
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Java13CommandLauncher.java:41) 
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:428) 
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:442) 
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:628) 
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:669) 
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:495) 
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292) 
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) 
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106) 
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348) 
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435) 
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456) 
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393) 
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364) 
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41) 
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248) 
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851) 
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235) 
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280) 
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109) 
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory 
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method) 
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:135) 
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130) 
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022) 
... 23 more
```

Kindly help me in this.

-gowtham

Comment: Jenkins (or Tomcat/...) won't source your bash_profile. Maybe you could add the path in `/etc/defaults` or somehow directly in Jenkins. What OS do you have (Ubuntu/...)? Which Servlet container is executing Jenkins?

Comment: thanks for the info !!! i have fixed down this issue, by manullay adding an environment file through environment file plugin provided by jenkins

Comment: Great! You could do the comunity a favour and answer your own question with a few more words how to solve this problem. This might be interesting for others as well.

Comment: @gowthamanivel Can you help me, How to setup jenkins with Sencha CMD.?

Answer (score 1):

Inorder to solve this issue,
1) install Envfile Plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Envfile+Plugin)
2) this plugin accept file(any extension) which can contain the all environment variables for example if you want export a path like sencha path for eyour project or increasing jvm memory size you can add those commands in a file and provide it path on jenkins

As per my problem concern sencha was configured for particular user bash profile. i just copied all of the bash profile content in new file and given the same file in jenkins plugin so each and every command whenever jenkins execute it will load all this envrionment file content.